# Proving there are infinitely many rational numbers in $[x,y]$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

> Prove if $x$ and $y$ are real numbers with $x \lt y$, then there are infinitely many rational numbers in the interval $[x,y]$.

What I got so far:

Let $x,y \in \Bbb R$ with $x \lt y$

Let $S = [x,y]$

By the density of $\Bbb Q$ in $\Bbb R$, $\exists r \in \Bbb Q$ such that $x \lt r \lt y$ where $r \in S$.

---

This is where I got stuck.

Comment: do the same with the interval $[x,r]$... and repeat and repeat infinitely many times (use induction if you prefer)

Comment: @dmtri This is not the correct way to do it. Example : $x=0$ and $y=2$. You will pick a rational in every $[1/n, 2-1/n]$, but how can you know that you are not picking the rational $1$ at each step ? Therefore, this does not tell you that $[0,2]$ contains an infinity of rationals.

Comment: @TheSivlerDoe,  you are right,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I'll give it another shot given the feedback.

Proof:

Let $x,y \in \Bbb R$ with $x \lt y$ and $S = [x,y]$

Suppose there are only $n$ rational numbers between $x$ and $y$ such that:$$x \lt r_1 \lt \cdot \cdot \cdot \lt r_n \lt y$$

But since $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, there exists $r_{n+1} \in \Bbb Q$ such that: $$ x \lt r_{n+1} \lt r_1  \lt \cdot \cdot \cdot \lt r_n \lt y$$

which contradicts our assumption that there are only $n$ rational numbers in $[x,y]$.

Therefore, there must be infinitely many rational numbers in the interval $[x,y]$.

Comment: @Robert Shore, how's this?

Comment: Slightly sloppy but fundamentally correct.  As framed, it only works if $n \geq 2$, because you need that in order to know that there are $r_k$ and $r_{k+1}$ to stuff the new rational between.  Better to simply put the new rational between $x$ and $r_1$.  Finally, I think you know that $x \lt r_1$, not just that $x \leq r_1$.

Comment: @RobertShore thank you for the feedback

Comment: With your newest edits, it's now correct.  As a matter of exposition, I'd probably elaborate a little (a phrase or a sentence) on the contradiction that you've demonstrated but your math and your logic are both correct.

Answer (score 4):

If you have only $n$ finitely many rational numbers between $x$ and $y$, put them in order, $x, r_1, r_2, \ldots r_n, y$.  Can you now prove that there were more than $n$ rational numbers between $x$ and $y$?  If so, you have contradicted your original assumption that there were only $n$ such numbers, which means no such $n$ can exists and there must be infinitely many rational numbers between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: I wrote out a new proof on this thread. Care to critique?

Answer (score 2):

Just find two distinct rational numbers $p,q\in[x,y]$. Now the rational number $p+(q-p)/n$ is in $[x,y]$ for all $n\in \Bbb N_{>0}$.

(And you can find such $p,q$ in the intervals $[x,x+(y-x)/3]$ and $[x+2(y-x)/3,y]$.)

Answer (score -1):

Consider the interval $[x,y]$.  Find two rational numbers $q_{min}$ and $q_{max}$ such that $x < q_{min} < q_{max} < y$.  Let $r=q_{min}-q_{max}$.  Now make a new number: $q_1 = q_{min} + r/2$.  Let $r_1=q_{max}-q_1$.  Now make a new number: $q_2=q_1+r_1/2$.  Let $r_2=q_{max}-q_2$.  Follow the pattern.  Each of these numbers is a rational number; each number is unique.  The set constructed is countably infinite in size.

Comment: We are not given that $x$ and $y$ are rational. So your numbers will not in general be rational.

Comment: @TonyK  Did I fix it?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But that $q^{(1)}$ notation is hard on the eyes!

Comment: @TonyK  Tough customer.  :)

Comment: And now you have two different $q_1$'s...

Comment: @TonyK  I think I have it.  Thanks for your help.